# Is this integral posible?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis, indefinite-integrals

I'm  studing Vector Calculus and my teacher gave to me a bunch of problems as homework, one of the problems was to evaluate $\int_{c}^{}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$ with $\vec{F}(x,y,z)= \left \langle yz e^{x},zx e^{y},xy e^{z} \right \rangle$ and $\vec{r}(t)=\left \langle \sin{t},\cos{t},\tan{t} \right \rangle$ for $0\leq t\leq \pi/4$.

I know that $\vec{F}(r(t))=\left \langle \sin{t}\; 
e^{\sin{t}},\sin{t}\;\tan{t}\; e^{cost},\sin{t}\; \cos{t} e^{\tan{t}} \right \rangle$ and $d\vec{r}(t)=\left \langle \cos{t},-\sin{t}, \sec^{2}{t} \right \rangle dt$ therefore

$\int_{c}^{}\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\left \langle \sin{t}\; 
e^{\sin{t}},\sin{t}\;\tan{t}\; e^{cost},\sin{t}\; \cos{t} e^{\tan{t}}  \right \rangle \cdot \left \langle \cos{t},-\sin{t}, \sec^{2}{t}  \right \rangle dt$

then $\int_{c}^{}\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\cos{t}\sin{t}e^{\sin{t}}-\sin^{2}{t}\tan{t}\; e^{\cos{t}}+ \tan{t}\; e^{\tan{t}})dt$, and here comes my question.

Is it posible to do this last integral analytically? I mean, the first two integral are a simple substitution and with a proper substitution the last one became the exponential integral. As far as I know, $\int_{}^{} \tan{t}\; e^{\tan{t}}dt$ can't be done analytically, however my teacher told me it was posible. I thought I could do it by the Laplace Transform method, but I couldn't figure out how. I do not know if there is something that I am not considering at the moment or if I do not fully understand some part of the theory behind all.

Comment: Finally, they can be expressed in terms of exponential integrals $Ei(z)]$, with real and complex arguments.

Comment: For the third term with $\tan$, consider substitution $\tan t = u$ and you will get a nice formula for the integral since $\tan^{2}t +1 = \sec^{2}t$.

Comment: Your professor probably messed up the vector field to use another trick. There are tricks you could use to turn this into a conservative vector field, e.g. on the curve $yz=x$ so you could turn the first component into $xe^x$, etc for the other components, but those still result in non analytic integrals. You could try to come up with a surface to use Stokes theorem, but both the surface and the curl would be god awful because this spiral is not an easy boundary.

Comment: @NinadMunshi's suggestion of using Stokes theorem is probably how you are intended to solve it. The curve $c$ is open, but it lies in the cylinder of radius $1$ about the $z$-axis. To close it, you can drop down from $\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}2, \frac{\sqrt 2}2, 1\right)$ to $\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}2, \frac{\sqrt 2}2, 0\right)$, then go back to $(0,1,0)$. On both of those sections, the curve integral is easy to calculate. If the area integral is easy as well (I haven't checked, but $d\vec A$ is simple on a cylinder), then you can use them to find the indicated value.